# C# Double Parsing Giving an error when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I am working on a C# project. I am parsing the values of datagridview and format them but the problem is all the values are being parsed perfectly except 1. It is so interesting and this is the first time I face this kind of situation.

```
for (int i=0; i<dgKisiFatura.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    for (int j = 3; j < dgKisiFatura.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dgKisiFatura.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = string.Format("{0:n2}",
          Math.Round(double.Parse(dgKisiFatura.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()), 2));

        dgKisiFatura.Columns[j].DefaultCellStyle.Font = fontSayi;
    }
```

The problem is it is parsing all the values bellow except one, **240000‬**

These are the exact string I am setting to `DataGridView`.

```
dgKisiFatura.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value =   "4320000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value =   "1680000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[2].Cells[4].Value =    "600000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[3].Cells[4].Value =    "540000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[4].Cells[4].Value =    "600000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[5].Cells[4].Value =   "1800000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[6].Cells[4].Value =    "240000‬"; // <- Here is the problem
dgKisiFatura.Rows[7].Cells[4].Value =   "1800000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[8].Cells[4].Value =    "480000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[9].Cells[4].Value =   "1440000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[10].Cells[4].Value =   "360000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[11].Cells[4].Value =   "900000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[12].Cells[4].Value =   "120000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[13].Cells[4].Value =  "2160000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[14].Cells[4].Value =   "900000";
dgKisiFatura.Rows[15].Cells[4].Value = "17940000";
```

I put all these in try and catch block and it is parsing perfectly except `240000‬`.

[image: This is the MessageBox that shows where the error happened]

And it just passes that value if I use try/catch and keeps working perfectly.
I need your help. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok it was givin FormatException over and over again. I go and get some tea and it fixed itself. I am still wondering what is going on here. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Comment: What type of tea? We need all relevant info to debug

Comment: @MatthewEvans the good stuff I'm assuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same idea as in TheGeneral's answer, but in slightly different representation (when working with `string`s, *characters* are often more convenient then bytes). Let's have a look at the string's *dump*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string data = "240000‬"; // Copy + Paste from the question

  string dump = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    data.Select(c => $"'{c}' (\\u{(int)c:x4})"));

  Console.Write(dump);
```

**Outcome:**

```
'2' (\u0032)
'4' (\u0034)
'0' (\u0030)
'0' (\u0030)
'0' (\u0030)
'0' (\u0030)
'‬' (\u202c)   <- the very reason of misbehavior
```

As we can see, `data` ends on **invisible** unicode character [\u202c](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm) (POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING), and that's why `data` can't be parsed into `double`

Comment: Thank you so much. The interesting thing is it fixed itself.

Answer (score 2):

`"240000‬"` has a weird unprintable character at the end of it `48 32`

You can better see it with

```
var result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("240000‬");
```

Work out why that is there, stop it from happening, and you have fixed your problem

[Online Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C95CnG)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I didn't get what you mean saying "weird unprintable character at the end of it". I checked the link you send. Can u explain a little bit more ? Thank you so much again.
Btw it fixed itself. I have no idea why, I didn't change anything.

Comment: @Muhammed Lutfu ODABASOGLU: print out string dump: `string data = "240000‬";       string dump = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Select(c => $"'{c}' (\\u{(int)c:x4})")); Console.Write(dump);` and you'll see `'‬' (\u202c)` at the end - `POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (U+202C)` unicode char.